# Varnish cache with only 1 IP?

Tags: apache, magento, caching, varnish, plesk

I'm starting my adventure with the Varnish Cache. Still have some questions about it, I couldn't find the straight answer.

Can I use Varnish cache server v.3.0.6 with eg. Plesk web hosting control panel, and have some domain (virtual hosts) with only 1 IP?

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

If Plesk web hosting allows you to setup different ports on the same ip you can use varnish as frontend on port 80 or 443(https) and let varnish communicate to a different port on the same server to retrieve the webpages.

in your vcl you can add the following host

```
backend website {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}
```